Existence of the pre transpose of an ultraweakly continuous linear map between duals
I found a result in a book that seemed well known but i can't prove it. Here it is.
Let $X, Y$ be two normed, complete TVS. Given an ultraweakly continuous (or weak* continuous) linear map $F : Y^* \rightarrow X^*$, there exists a unique bounded linear map $S: X \rightarrow Y$ such that $S^t=F$.
To be more specific, i want to recover such an $S$ from $F$, with $X = T(H_1), Y=T(H_2)$ and therefore $X^*=B(H_1), Y^*=B(H_2)$. Here, $H_1$ and $H_2$ are infinite dimensional hilbert spaces, and $T(H)$ is the space of trace class operators, which is the predual of $B(H)$, the space of bounded operators.
Thank you for your help.

Let $F: Y^\ast \to X^\ast$ be weak$^\ast$ continuous. Then for any $x \in X$, it induces an weak$^\ast$ continuous linear functional $\text{ev}_x$ on $X^\ast$, defined by $\text{ev}_x(\varphi) = \varphi(x)$. Since $F$ is weak$^\ast$ continuous, $\text{ev}_x \circ F$ is a weak$^\ast$ continuous linear functional on $Y^\ast$. Hence it is of the form $\text{ev}_{Sx}$ for a unique $Sx \in Y$. This yields the desired map $S: X \to Y$. It isn’t hard to check it is linear and $S^t = F$. Boundedness of $S$ follows from closed graph theorem. Indeed, if $x_n \to x$ in $X$ and $Sx_n \to y$ in $Y$, then, for any $\varphi \in Y^\ast$,
$$\varphi(y) = \lim_n \varphi(Sx_n) = \lim_n (F\varphi)(x_n) = (F\varphi)(x) = \varphi(Sx)$$
As this holds for all $\varphi \in Y^\ast$, we have $Sx = y$.

Actually we could apply the closed graph theorem to $F$ to get that $F$ is bounded (which then implies that $S$ is bounded), that way we don't even need that $X,Y$ are complete
